# Unable to access local vaiable outside the function to another function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, global-variables, local-variables

I am unable  to access local variable data(latitude and longtitude) from fetchlocation() function to another function callAPI() function for fetching location .. That's why i used global variable q to fetch it but still showing error. here are code:

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {


lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

private val key = "5a812faf9e1e4a66b17223056210911"

private val days = 1

private var q:String=""

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity)

       

    fetchLocation()

     callAPI()
}

private fun fetchLocation() {

    val task =fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation


    if (context?.let { ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) }
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context?.let {
            ActivityCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(it,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),101)
        return
    }
    task.addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it!= null){

            q="$it.latitude,$it.longitude"
        }
    }
}

private fun callAPI(){  
    apiServices.getUserDetails(key, q, days).enqueue(
       )
   }
```

}

Comment: Short answer: move `callAPI()` inside `addOnSuccessListener { }`. Or, if you want to keep both functions decoupled, return `q` in a callback or as a `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big problem with your code. You need to `fetchLocation()` to update  q variable then you invoke `callAPI()` but in case users do not provide their location permission so you do not invoke `callAPI()` too.

You can try this solution:

```
private fun fetchLocation(result: (String) -> Unit) {

    val task =fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation


    if (context?.let { ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) }
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context?.let {
            ActivityCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(it,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),101)
        return
    }
    task.addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it!= null){

            result("$it.latitude,$it.longitude")
        }
    }
}

private fun callAPI(q: String){  
    apiServices.getUserDetails(key, q, days).enqueue(
       )
   }

fetchLocation() { q ->
  callAPI(q)
}
```